# Quero digitar um número e ele seja multiplicado de 1 até 10

Tags: java, algoritmo

```
package exercicio5;
import java.util.*;

public class Exercicio5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i,n1,x;

        Scanner ler;
        ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
            x=n1*i;
            System.out.println("Digite o 1°número" +n1);
            n1 = ler.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Multiplicação de 1 até 10" +x);
        }
    }  
}
```

Está dando erro em: `x=n1*i;`

Comment: E o que deveria ser `n1` na primeira iteração? Você só leu o valor dele depois dessa linha...

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O erro é que não inicializou a variável para usá-la, inicializando resolveria o problema. Mas esse código pode ser simplificado e a variável nem ser necessária, inclusive havia um erro de lógica fazendo conta antes do momento que dá para fazer e imprimindo uma informação errada sobre qual é o número que está digitando. Organizando melhor e usando um padrão mais próximo do que as pessoas fazem:

```
package exercicio5;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Digite o 1°numero" + i);
            int n = ler.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Multiplicação de 1 até 10" + n * i);
        }
    }  
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KeQp4m). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ReadValuejava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/ReadValue.java).

Comment: package exercicio5;
import java.util.*;

public class Exercicio5 {

  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i,n = 0,x;
        
        Scanner ler;
        ler = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Digite o número" +n);
           n = ler.nextInt();
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
         
          x=n*i;
     
            System.out.println("Multiplicação de 1 até 10 " +x);
      
           
    }
}  
}
consegui fazer era mais ou menos assim que eu queria vou tentar mais organizado exemplo n que eu digitar n*1,n*2,n*3 etc...

Comment: continua errado e desorganizado